# Moving a image slider as a whole over a few pixels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know how to set my image slider or "carousel" to be always 30 percent away from the left side of the browser. I would also not like to have my image slider shrink at all when the page gets to small.

Link to my site: http://rootforsite.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: _"30 percent away from the left side of the browser and 70 percent away from the right side"_ Wouldn't that make it 0% wide?

Comment: good point... how about just 30 percent from the left side how would i do that?

Comment: I basically want to move my image slider a bit over to the left.

Comment: Mr Alex That you can do by Just giving 'margin-left:30%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some code that looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="" style="width: 1130px; margin: 0px auto;">
... blah blah other code ...
```

Which basically centers your carousel.

Change that margin to `margin: 0 30% 0 auto`, so it's always 30% from the left side. So it'd look like:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="" style="width: 1130px; margin: 0 30% 0 auto;">
... blah blah other code ...
```